# How to return the value of a reference field of a struct that is no longer used without copy?

Tags: rust

Code like this:

```
pub fn sample_from_categorical_logits(prob_logits: Tensor) -> (Tensor, Tensor) {
    let prob_obj = match prob_logits.size().len() {
        3 => Categorical::from_logits(prob_logits),
        2 => Categorical::from_logits(prob_logits.unsqueeze(1)),
        _ => panic!("illegal..."),
    };
    (prob_obj.sample(&[]), (*prob_obj.probs()).copy())//TODO: can copy be avoided?
}
```

I can get an immutable reference on a field of object `prob_obj` through `prob_obj.prob()`. Now I need to return the value of it, because I need to read(only) this value for some calculation, and return this value and calculated value further.

`Tensor` is a 3rd struct doesn't implement `Copy` trait.

I know I can't return a reference of a local object.  But in this case, since I no longer need the whole `prob_obj` object, I wonder if there is a more efficient way other than copying the field, like `move` in C++.

I googled, found something like `Cow`, `Mem::take`, and `UnSafe`, but they seem to be not the use case here.

Comment: You can't just move a value out of a private field, even if the struct itself is about to be dropped. The API you're using needs to support this. Sometimes it'll offer something like `fn take_prob(self) -> Prob` which consumes `self` by value and returns the inner object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a more efficient way other than copying the field, like move in C++.

Well yes, moving. But moving requires having ownership of the object, meaning you need a version of `probs()` which *consumes* the object in order to return its bits.

Or one which returns a mutable reference in order to use `mem::take` or `mem::swap`.

Like you would in C++, really, it's not like you can just move stuff out of a const reference (at best that's going to perform a copy).

Comment: So, does it mean that no way to get the field other than copying it, as long as `probs()` returns an immutable reference?

Comment: Well yes, you can't get ownership of something you don't own.